# HiddenField.Value is an empty string upon postback inside my custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I have a custom control that has a hidden field. Upon postback I want to obtain the value stored in it, but it's always an empty string. any thoughts?

I am performing client-side manipulation of the hidden field values and have verified in firebug that the fields are correct before issue a post back

Here is the setup:

```
public class DualListPanel : SWebControl, INamingContainer

    {

        protected IList<DlpItem> UnassignedList { get; set; }
        protected IList<DlpItem> AssignedList { get; set; }
        private HiddenField assignedItemsField, unassignedItemsField;

        public DualListPanel()
        {
            CssClass = "DualListPanel";
            EnableViewState = true;
        }

        #region ViewState

        protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
        {
            var state = savedState as object[];
            UnassignedList =   state[0] as List<DlpItem>;
            AssignedList = state[1] as List<DlpItem>;
            base.LoadViewState(state[2]);
        }

        protected override object SaveViewState()
        {
            object[] state = new object[3];
            state[0] = UnassignedList;
            state[1] = AssignedList;
            state[2] = base.SaveViewState();
            return state;
        }

        #endregion

        #region WebControl Overrides


        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
            GetUnassignedList(); //omitted method
            GetAssignedList(); //omitted method
            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {          
            assignedItemsField = new HiddenField();
            assignedItemsField.ID = "HiddenAssignedItems";
            assignedItemsField.EnableViewState = true;

            unassignedItemsField = new HiddenField();
            unassignedItemsField.ID = "HiddenUnassignedItems";
            unassignedItemsField.EnableViewState = true;

            Controls.Add(assignedItemsField);
            Controls.Add(unassignedItemsField);
            base.CreateChildControls();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Item Lists Retrieval

        public string GetCommaDelimUnassignedItems()
        {
            return unassignedItemsField.Value;
        }

        public string GetCommaDelimAssignedItems()
        {
            return assignedItemsField.Value;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that there is no a direct relationship such that if I change the markup client-side, that the HiddenField server-side will reflect those changes (assumption there is that it reads the markup to assign .Value)? If so then is there a different approach to discerning the value server-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugggh I omitted information that would have been useful. I was primarily testing if I could access the values during the page cycle process. Not necessarily from a page calling 
GetCommaDelimUnassignedItems();

I realized I had implemented OnInit() and made calls to check the value (I omitted it thinking it was not useful to the issue). Completely forgot that the ViewState will not be loaded during OnInit(). I changed it to OnPreRender() and it's working fine now

Answer (score 2):

I think hidden field's value does not lost during postback,
Put your code in Ispostback, whenever you initialize hidden fields.

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()         
{                      
 if(!ispostback){
 assignedItemsField = new HiddenField();     
 assignedItemsField.ID = "HiddenAssignedItems";
 assignedItemsField.EnableViewState = true;          
 unassignedItemsField = new HiddenField();           
 unassignedItemsField.ID = "HiddenUnassignedItems"; 
 unassignedItemsField.EnableViewState = true;      
 Controls.Add(assignedItemsField);             
 Controls.Add(unassignedItemsField);          
 base.CreateChildControls();      
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you simply need to mark your 2 hidden fields `protected` instead of `private`.

Comment: I'll give it a swing. Any explanation as to why if this works?

Comment: Changed them to protected and still no go. I went into debug mode and ensured that they are empty strings still

Comment: It was just a wild stab at it as I've had problems when manually declaring controls.  The protected thing is only for accessing controls in both markup and code-behind apparently...